# Send data from one laptop(code blocks) to another laptop(ros packages)?

Tags: roscpp, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi im doing a project whereby my robot will be controlled remotely. But I met a obstacle. I have a Qt design over at my client side, with buttons that are supposed to control the robot, but how do I send it over to the server side which is running ros packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11508/send-data-from-one-laptop(code-blocks)-to-another-laptop(ros-packages)?/) by [cheyanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/1055/cheyanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS solution would be to make your Qt GUI a ROS package and send messages to the client side. I would recommend to do it that way. It is fairly easy if you know Qt already.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-10-13**:
Your Qt GUI is built with code blocks, right? You would create a ROS package with code blocks like here http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#CodeBlocks and make it a Qt GUI. Other than creating the package for code blocks everything is standard ROS.

**Comment by [cheyanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/1055/cheyanne/) on 2011-10-12**:
So u mean I have my qt as ros package and also code blocks on client side, then how do I send it to the server side?